# To install data to csv column wise

Tags: php

I have tried this and it is perfectly working for row wise.

```
// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="demo.csv"');

// do not cache the file
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// send the column headers
fputcsv($file, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5'));

// Sample data. This can be fetched from mysql too
$data = array(
    array('Data 11', 'Data 12', 'Data 13', 'Data 14', 'Data 15'),
    array('Data 21', 'Data 22', 'Data 23', 'Data 24', 'Data 25'),
    array('Data 31', 'Data 32', 'Data 33', 'Data 34', 'Data 35'),
    array('Data 41', 'Data 42', 'Data 43', 'Data 44', 'Data 45'),
    array('Data 51', 'Data 52', 'Data 53', 'Data 54', 'Data 55')
);

// output each row of the data
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    fputcsv($file, $row);
}

exit();
```

But i want it to install like column wise. Means, it is now

```
'Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5'
'Data 11', 'Data 12', 'Data 13', 'Data 14', 'Data 15'
'Data 21', 'Data 22', 'Data 23', 'Data 24', 'Data 25'
```

But i want like this

```
'Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5'
'Data 11', 'Data 21', 'Data 31', 'Data 41', 'Data 51'
```

Is this possible or is there any trick to do that ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to organize your array first to match desired result with nested `foreach` loops

```
$result = [];                        // Grouped result array
foreach ($data as $value) {          // Loop thru each data array
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {   // Loop thru each data
        $result[$k][] = $v;          // Group all elements with same index
    }
}

// output each row of the data
foreach ($result as $row)            // Loop thru grouped result array
{
    fputcsv($file, $row);
}
```

Sample result array would be like this

```
$result = array (
    array ('Data 11', 'Data 21', 'Data 31', 'Data 41', 'Data 51'),
    array ('Data 12', 'Data 22', 'Data 32', 'Data 42', 'Data 52'),
    array ('Data 13', 'Data 23', 'Data 33', 'Data 43', 'Data 53'),
    array ('Data 14', 'Data 24', 'Data 34', 'Data 44', 'Data 54'),
    array ('Data 15', 'Data 25', 'Data 35', 'Data 45', 'Data 55')
);
```